# Entity Framework Eager load only a subset of other tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

In the legacy system I'm working on, every single table supports soft deleting through a flag called `IsActive`. How can I use Entity Framework's eager loading through the `Include` method, but only eager load a subset of the table that are active (not soft deleted), rather than all of it.

#### Example:

Consider two tables `Document` and `Section`, where a `Document` contains a set of `Section`s and I want to load `Document`s with their active (not soft deleted) `Section`s eagerly loaded. This is a schema in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78e71/2).

In SQL I achieve this with this query:

```
SELECT 
    D.*, S.* 
FROM 
Document D
INNER JOIN Section S ON S.DocumentId = D.Id AND S.IsActive = 1
WHERE D.IsActive = 1
```

See the active flag checks on the `ON` clause of the join as well as the `WHERE` clause.

In EF I tried:

```
_context.Set<Document>()
        .Include(d => d.Sections)
        .All(d => d.IsActive);
```

It works but eagerly loads both active and inactive sections.

I also tried this:

```
_context.Set<Document>()
        .Include(d => d.Sections.Where(sec => sec.IsActive))
        .All(d => d.IsActive);
```

but it throws a runtime exceptions; it seems EF doesn't like `Where` inside `Include`.

I'm using Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use association fixup.

```
var result = _context.Set<Document>()
    .Where(d => d.IsActive)
    .Select(d =>
    new
    {
        Document = d,
        Sections = d.Sections.Where(s => s.IsActive)
    })
    .ToArray().Select(anonymous => anonymous.Document).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think `Document` will still contain a set of active and inactive sections. Unless I somehow assign `anonymous.Sections` to `anonymous.Document.Sections`.

Comment: nope, they will automatically connected, it's called association fix-up, you could try it and check the result, each active document will only contain active section..